# How to catch this SignalR exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, async-await

I have an ASP.NET Web Api that uses SignalR to communicate real-time data to mobile clients. Everything is working well, but I see an exception in my trace logs and I can't seem to catch or handle this exception:

```
Application: 2014-05-20T03:24:57  PID[2088] Warning     SignalR exception thrown by Task: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
Application:    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
Application:    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
Application:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
Application:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
Application:    at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
Application:    at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
Application:    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.OutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerResponse.Write(ArraySegment`1 data)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.BinaryTextWriter.<.ctor>b__4(ArraySegment`1 data, Object state)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.BufferTextWriter.ChunkedWriter.Flush(Byte[] byteBuffer, Boolean flushEncoder)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.BufferTextWriter.ChunkedWriter.Flush(Boolean flushEncoder)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.BufferTextWriter.Flush()
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport.PerformKeepAlive(Object state)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport.<KeepAlive>b__0(Object state)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.TaskQueue.<Enqueue>b__1(Func`2 next, Object nextState)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod[T1,T2](Func`3 func, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
Application:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Application: ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Web.HttpException (0x800704CD): The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
Application:    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
Application:    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
Application:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
Application:    at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush()
Application:    at System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
Application:    at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
Application:    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.OutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerResponse.Write(ArraySegment`1 data)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.BinaryTextWriter.<.ctor>b__4(ArraySegment`1 data, Object state)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.BufferTextWriter.ChunkedWriter.Flush(Byte[] byteBuffer, Boolean flushEncoder)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.BufferTextWriter.ChunkedWriter.Flush(Boolean flushEncoder)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.BufferTextWriter.Flush()
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport.PerformKeepAlive(Object state)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.ServerSentEventsTransport.<KeepAlive>b__0(Object state)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.TaskQueue.<Enqueue>b__1(Func`2 next, Object nextState)
Application:    at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod[T1,T2](Func`3 func, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)<---
```

All of my code is wrapped in try/catch statements and I have an unobserved exception handler defined using `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`. If I could catch it, I could flatten the aggregate exception and process each individually.

Does anyone know how I can catch or handle this exception? It seems to happen every few minutes. Thanks in advance - I've been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: Could you try: 
`Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler  (ErrorHandlerForm.Form1_UIThreadException);

// Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through 
// our handler.
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

// Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
    new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);`

Comment: `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` does not catch the exception at all?

Comment: TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException is not catching it...

Comment: The Dutch Man -- Is it possible to use Application.ThreadException in an ASP.NET Web Api project??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to catch it with `HttpApplication.Error`, more details here:

[Processing Unhandled Exceptions](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/processing-unhandled-exceptions-cs)

Yet I'm surprised that none of your `catch` block is getting triggered. Are you sure you're wrapping *every* `Task`? You may want to try something like `task.WithObservation()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23771876/1768303).

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried HttpApplication.Error and it's not catching anything, but I'm still working on your Task.WithObservation() suggestion. That link has led me to several of your other posts - all really good, learning a lot from them.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out. Thanks again for the help so far - learned a lot from your posts.

Comment: @Ender2050, you could try to catch it first as [first-chance exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997368(v=vs.110).aspx). This won't solve the problem, but may help with troubleshooting.

Comment: This error is intermittent so I'm not certain - but I think I have this working using the approach you outlined in your second link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766808/why-doesnt-this-exception-get-thrown/23771876#23771876. Very helpful, thank you again.